# How to rename GCC paths

Tags: 7

I'm using Groups, Communities and Co (7.x-1.0-beta2) and I'd like to rename the paths that are used. As currently it uses the format:

```
#node#/gcc
#node#/gcc/members
#node#/gcc/role
#node#/gcc/permissions
```

and I'd prefer it to be:

```
#node#/group
#node#/group/members
#node#/group/role
#node#/group/permissions
```

Can this be done without going into the module code and renaming the variables directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 parts to this question:

1. How to make Drupal accept second paths? Go to http://example.com/admin/config/search/path and set aliases for them. You can use [Pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) to automate this process, or try one of the modules that allows wildcards in aliases.
2. How to make Drupal generate proper paths? Well, if above will not assure this, use [Global Redirect](https://drupal.org/project/globalredirect) - it'll make sure only aliases are visible to your users.

Comment: With (1) are you suggesting clicking 'Add alias' on the 'URL aliases' page and manually creating aliases for each of the nodes that will use GCC? As I will need to process to be automated.

Comment: @RebDev updated my answer. For me Pathauto is a must and I sometimes forget not everyone have it.

Comment: With many groups and multiple sub paths would it be better to use a module that allows wildcards in aliases or to generate new Pathauto aliases for each path/sub path when a new group is created?